# Elasticsearch nested bool queries with geo_distance filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have to make query no Elasticsearch which would get all cabinets from Paris ( using arrondissements) but also to get cabinets around the paris in radius of 20km

This is my query:

The problem here is in **second bool query**

because it doesn't respect `geo_distance filter` to show cabinets only 20km around the Paris.

Please if you have any idea how it could be done I would really appreciate .

Best Regards,
Bojan

Comment: i am not able to get what you are trying to say with "but it doesn't respect geo_distance_filter to show cabinets only 20Km around the paris". can you share the error you are getting or the code you have been running to query for your case

Comment: can you also add your mappings, do you have geo point in the documents